# How to use java sound api in raspberry pi board?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, microphone

I am using the code for the speechrecognizer below in Raspberry pi board.To transfer files, I am exporting `jar` file from eclipse to raspberry pi board.

Jar file is working in windows environment properly but it's not working with Rasbian OS. Java version in windows end rasbian is **1.8.0_211**.

Rasbian see usb microphone.(using pulseaudio volume control)

**Error message:**

> microphone is not available from the CLI" What is the problem?

**Code:**

```
/*
 * Starting a Thread that checks if the resources needed to the 
 * SpeechRecognition library are available
 */

public void startResourcesThread() {

    //Check lock
    if (resourcesThreadRunning)
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Resources Thread already running...\n");
    else
        //Submit to ExecutorService
        eventsExecutorService.submit(() -> {
            try {

                //Lock
                resourcesThreadRunning = true;

                // Detect if the microphone is available
                while (true) {

                    //Is the Microphone Available
                    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE))
                        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Microphone is not available.\n");

                    // Sleep some period
                    Thread.sleep(350);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
                resourcesThreadRunning = false;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: As a test, what does Port.Info.LINE_IN return?

Comment: yes same problem again